# How to affect a view in an android activity based on a Firebase transaction outcome

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, view, transactions

I have the following Firebase transaction in my activity:

```
private void onRoomAccept(DatabaseReference thisRoomRef) {
        thisRoomRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
            @Override
            public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                Room r = mutableData.getValue(Room.class);

                if (r != null && r.State.equals("Open")) {

                    r.Tutor = UserID;
                    r.State = "Live";

                    // Set value and report transaction success
                    mutableData.setValue(r);
                    return Transaction.success(mutableData);

                } else if (r == null || r.State.equals("Live")){
                    Intent intent3 = new Intent(TutorChatActivity.this, TutorActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent3);
                }
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                               DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Transaction completed
            Log.d(TAG, "postTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
        }
    });
}
```

This works fine. However, I want to build some view changes on top of it. For example, if the transaction is a success (meaning that the updated 'r' value is set in the database), I want to change button visibility.

The following was added into the transaction to cause the error given further down:

```
Positive.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
Negative.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Likewise, for the unsuccessful outcome, I want to make a dialog popup stating that there was a failure, before bouncing the user back to, in this case, the TutorActivity.

I attempted this but got an error stating that only the activity can make changes to its own views (which kind of makes sense to me):

```
postTransaction:onComplete:DatabaseError: User code called from the Firebase Database runloop threw an exception:
                                                                           android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:7901)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:1360)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:5448)
                                                                               at android.view.View.invalidateInternal(View.java:14829)
                                                                               at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:14793)
                                                                               at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:12684)
                                                                               at android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:8673)
                                                                               at website.picl.picl.Activities.TutorChatActivity$7.doTransaction(TutorChatActivity.java:365)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdsf.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.firebase.database.zzf.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
```

So, going back to my question, how would I otherwise use the outcome from the transaction to change my views (without necessarily using a separate value event listener, which I would only consider as a last option, due to it being slower and resulting in more server calls).

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase database client, runs all network operations in a background thread. So this means that you cannot create / modify views within that background thread. You can modify the UI only in the thread where those views were created. However, the thread in which you are allowed to make those changes is the main thraed, so you need to get those lines of code out of the transaction.

The solution in your case would be, to add a `ValueEventListener` (outside the transaction) on that particular value and once the transaction succeeded, the `onDataChange()` method will be called and inside this method you can create / modify as many views as you want.

**Note:** The entire view tree is single threaded. So, you must always be on the UI thread when calling any method on any view. If you are doing work on other threads and want to update the state of a view from that thread, you should use a `Handler`.

You can find much more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html).

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to interacte with the views within my activity without relying on a separate listener:

I insert the following into the IF statement within my transaction code, as shown in my original question:

```
getIntent().removeExtra("ORIGIN");
getIntent().putExtra("ORIGIN", "TransactionSuccess");
startActivity(getIntent());
```

Then, in the onCreate of my activity, I handle my required view changes in the case for which ORIGIN is equal to "TransactionSuccess", in an IF statement:

```
//This is in my onCreate:

Intent intent = getIntent();
String origin = intent.getStringExtra("ORIGIN");

if (origin.equals("TransactionSuccess"){

this.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

//Set my view changes here.

}
```

Additionally, to avoid the slide in animation upon the activity refresh, I include the following in the same onCreate IF statement (as shown):

```
this.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

This approach allows for a faster view change than relying on a database listener.

There is still a momentary flash of the existing views, as the activity is restarted, but I'll take that over the comparatively longer waiting time of the listener.